# Return arrow as a type in Swift

Tags: swift, uikit

```
var textFieldChangedHandler: ((String) -> Void)?
```

What does it mean when you use the return arrow when declaring the type of a variable in Swift?

Comment: This is a closure. I recommend read all new Swift programmers (coming from other languages, not first time programmers) read the Swift language guide, cover-to-cover. Otherwise you'll just be stuck in a cycle of asking questions like this and getting piecemeal answers.

Comment: Awesome thank you for the advice, would you mind referencing this specific guide or book?

Comment: [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/).  Also available for free through the iPad/iPhone Books app.

Answer (score 0):

It's the return closure say you in `ClassA` and you need to send data to other place say `ClassB` then do

in `ClassA`

```
var textFieldChangedHandler: ((String) -> Void)?

 func send() {
    textFieldChangedHandler?(value)
  }
```

Then in `classB`

```
  let cl = ClassA()
  cl.textFieldChangedHandler = { str in 
     print(str)
  }
```